# Why is $H = \left\{ \left(\begin{array}{rl} z_1&z_2\\ -\bar z_2&\bar z_1 \end{array}\right) \bigg\vert \ z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb C \right\}$ closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

> Consider the set of matrices $$H = \left\{ \left(\begin{array}{rl} z_1&z_2\\ -\bar z_2&\bar z_1 \end{array}\right) \bigg\vert \ z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb C \right\}.$$ It is a four-dimensional real subspace of the vector space $L_2(\mathbb C)$, and enjoys the following remarkable properties:
>
> $1)$ $H$ is closed under multiplication, i.e., it is a real subalgebra of the algebra $L_2(\mathbb C)$;

I have tried to multiply it with this matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b 
 \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}

where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are complex numbers but I got a very big formula that I do not know how this formula still is in $H$. Is there any suggestions for proving this in a simpler way?

Comment: You have to be careful: the matrix you multiply by also has to be of the same form. Thus, $c = -\bar{b}$ and $d = \bar{a}$. I might write up a fuller explanation of how this holds in a second (if it does, I gotta check) - I just wanted to point out that since it seemed like the first likely place where you might have tripped up.

Comment: You multiply elements from H!

Comment: Find $$\begin{pmatrix} z_1 & z_2\\ -\bar{z_2}& \bar{z_1} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} w_1 & w_2\\ -\bar{w_2}& \bar{w_1} \end{pmatrix}$$ and arrange the entries in the required form!

Comment: @EeveeTrainer  ok I got your idea.

Comment: Notice that the space is one representation of the [Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion). See the section "Conjugation, the norm, and reciprocal".

Comment: yes correct .... I am working from Vinberg "Linear representations of groups" @Somos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, for a set $S$ of matrices (or any sort of element) to be closed under an operation $\ast$ on it, we require that, for all $a,b \in S, a \ast b \in S$.

As I noted in the comments, your issue lied in multiplying a matrix of $H$ by a generic matrix of complex elements, which is too general to have closure. You have to take two generic matrices ***of the set***. So, let $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb C$ and then consider the multiplication

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ 
-\bar{b} & \bar{a}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
c & d\\ 
-\bar{d} & \bar{c}
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
ac - b \bar{d} & ad+b\bar{c}\\ 
-\bar{a} \bar{d} - \bar{b}c & \bar{a} \bar{c}-\bar{b}d
\end{bmatrix} $$

You can see immediately the left two matrices are of the form of matrices in $H$; on the right is their product. You can verify that it, too, matches by noting a couple of properties of the complex conjugate:

$$\overline{z_1 \cdot z_2} = \overline{z_1} \cdot \overline{z_2} \;\;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\;\; \overline{z_1 + z_2} = \overline{z_1} + \overline{z_2} \;\;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\;\; \overline{\overline{z_1}} = z_1$$

where $z_1,z_2 \in \Bbb C$. So if...

- ...the bottom-left entry is the negative of the conjugate of the top-right
- ...the bottom-right entry is the conjugate of the top-left

...then the product is in the form for a matrix in $H$. It does happen to hold, and thus $H$ is closed under matrix multiplication.

Comment: I think the first term in the second element of the resulting matrix is ad not ab?

Comment: @hopefully Yeah, you're right, I made a typo. Thanks!

Comment: what about the terms that contain only one bar, like the second term of the bottom right entry?

Comment: What about them, exactly?

Comment: How can they be like the bottom right entry of the original matrix? the d must have a bar on it also to use the rules you mentioned

Comment: Also for the bottom left term the c must have a bar, correct?

Comment: Take the conjugate of the top-left entry and you see they are equal if you use the properties in my post (the conjugate of a sum/product is the sum/product of the conjugates). One property I *did* leave out was that the conjugate of a conjugate is the original number, so I will add that. But the core idea is effectively that each factor of a number, when you take the conjugate, becomes its conjugate.

Comment: I got the idea thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative method that, after verification of the simple characterization of this subspace given below, is coordinate-free.

**Hint** Denote $$J := \pmatrix{\cdot&-1\\1&\cdot}.$$ It follows immediately from the definition that $$\{X \in M(2, \Bbb C) : \textrm{$X$ satisfies $X^\dagger J = J X^\top$}\} .$$

> So, for $X, Y \in H$, $$(X Y)^\dagger J = Y^\dagger X^\dagger J = Y^\dagger JX^\top = J Y^\top X^\top = J (XY)^\top .$$